# Double search in mysql?

Tags: mysql, search, find, double, sql-like

I use this when searching for something:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM persons WHERE active != 'No' AND LOWER(firstname) LIKE '%$find%' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
```

And I would like to included an additional search parameter

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM persons WHERE active != 'No' AND LOWER(firstname) LIKE '%$find%' AND LOWER(lastname) LIKE '%$mytest%' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
```

But this does not seem to work. The second LIKE makes the result null. How to included a second search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct. If you don't get results check that the database has rows that should match.

By the way, you should read up on prepared statements. This code has an SQL injection vulnerability. Also,string comparisons are by default case insensitive, so you don't need to call LOWER.

Comment: Thank you, I was searching in the wrong table :facepalm:. And yes I do need to read up but... ah! time lol.